# Where is the Dynamic Language Runtime?

Tags: c#, scripting, dynamic-language-runtime

Alright, I have searched everywhere and read several articles on the subject, including MSDN, but I do not quite understand where these assemblies are located.  I know that some are part of the .NET Framework, but I can't find the rest of them, like Microsoft.Scripting, etc.  Could someone elaborate on where all the assemblies are located and give me the namespace in which the DLR types are found.  Do I need to download the project from Codeplex?  If so, what parts of it do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you will need to download it from CodePlex
2. Consult their documentation
3. Depends on what exactly you will be using it for (see 2)

Comment: Well, I am designing a grammar for Perl, so I am creating a compiler to generate IL for Perl scripts.  What parts of the opensource DLR are not included in .NET framework?  I know some of it is included in System.Dynamic and System.Core but the rest has evaded me.  Thanks for clearing that for me.